# Default Preprocessor Definitions & Cross-Platform compiling

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to figure a "clean way" of using the default preprocessor definitions to determine what parts of my code should be compiled based on the platform and compiler.

My current test setup involves a Windows machine with Visual C++ compiler and a Debian with g++ compiler.

Currently I have something like this:

```
#if defined (__GNUG__)
    #define ASMMath_EI __attribute__ ((__visibility__("default")))
#elif defined (WIN32)
    #ifdef ASMMath_EXPORTS
        #define ASMMath_EI __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define ASMMath_EI __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#endif

extern void ASMMath_EI AsmProblemOne();
```

And it works, but I figure there might and must be some better definitions I can check for. Or perhaps some more ideal way with CMake?
Suggestions?

Comment: Note that, when compiling with GCC on Windows, \_\_GNUG\_\_ is also set to true. Better use \_\_linux\_\_.

Comment: @Ionic Figured. I'm not exactly sure if I need the definition for *nix or g++.

Comment: Sorry, seems to be *nix-specific as per: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Comment: `_MSC_VER` is good definition for detecting MSVC.

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice listing of [Compiler](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/), [Operating System](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/), and [Architecture](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Architectures/) preprocessor names at those links. You could branch for the systems and compilers you care about supporting/detecting. Additionally a lot of this work is already done in `boost/config/` (see `boost/config/select_compiler_config.hpp` as one example for compiler flags) using Boost headers. Not everyone likes including Boost, which is why the first set of links is generic from library specific support.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by the OP in a question edit:

> From what I gather the following would be ideal way to implement this:
>
> ```
> // MasterHeader.h
> #if defined _MSC_VER // Defined by visual studio
>   #define PROJ_TMP_DLL_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
>   #define PROJ_TMP_DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
> #else
>   #if __GNUC__ >= 4 // Defined by GNU C Compiler. Also for C++
>     #define PROJ_TMP_DLL_IMPORT __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
>     #define PROJ_TMP_DLL_EXPORT __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
>   #else
>     #define PROJ_TMP_DLL_IMPORT
>     #define PROJ_TMP_DLL_EXPORT
>   #endif
> #endif
>
> #ifdef PROJ_EXPORTS
>     #define PROJ_API PROJ_TMP_DLL_EXPORT
> #else
>     #define PROJ_API PROJ_TMP_DLL_IMPORT
> #endif
> ```
>
> -
>
> ```
> // File.h
> #include "MasterHeader.h"
>
> extern void PROJ_API SomeFunction();
> ```

Comment: ([Answered in a question edit and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que))